# Read Email and set body as TextView Javamail API

Tags: java, android, smtp, jakarta-mail, pop3

I have Javamail API setup to send emails from a specific Gmail account. However, I am curious if there is a way to go through a small checklist, for example, if sender = "example@gmail.com" then grab the body of an incoming email and display the text content as a textView on an Android Application.

I have found a few methods of reading emails from a Gmail account. An example of what I'm currently using is as follows:

```
public class ReadingEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "yourEmailId@gmail.com", "password");

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");

            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
            Address[] in = msg.getFrom();

            for (Address address : in) {
                System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
            }

            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);

            System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
            System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());

        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

An example of an email would be:

[image]

The output of the example in the console would be:

[image]

However, my issue with this is that instead of using println statements to write to the console, I would like to read the inbox, check if the sender is a specific pre-defined email address, and if so take the text only of that email and display it to the android screen as a textView.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're confused about.  The JavaMail API has methods to access all the parts of the message.  The JavaMail FAQ has an example for [accessing the main body of a message](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that oracle had an FAQ. In the portion where it says, "You can call the getText method with a Message object (which is a Part)." What would be the preferred method to getText and set that to a textView?

Comment: I don't think there is a preferred way of doing that; it depends on the requirements and structure of your application.  Have you created the application that includes the textView and you're just trying to figure out how to put the data in the textView?

Comment: Precisely, the structure is essentially a 3 tabbed layout with fragments. I am trying to display the textView onto one of the fragments. I have not created a textView layout just yet, so anything goes. Essentially the idea is to grab the body of the email and display the text from it as a sort of dynamic news feed if that makes sense.

Comment: Well, if you get stuck, post the code that shows what you've tried and what happens when you try it.